# Facebook Like posting different to what debugger showing

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, feed

I cant figure this one out, i have built a site with an e commerce system and i want visitors to be able to like an individual product and thus that product be added to their feed.

I have added all the open graph code to the relevant place, but when someone clicks "Like" is shares a default thing rather than the perticular product. this is the one i have been using for an example

https://pinnaclesupplement.co.uk/index.php/shop/168/10/weight-gainers/serious-mass-2-72kg-detail

so I tried using the facebook debugger to see if i could figure it out, but thats is showing the correct info and exactly what i want to show up on peoples feeds! here is a link for that.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fpinnaclesupplement.co.uk%2Findex.php%2Fshop%2F168%2F10%2Fweight-gainers%2Fserious-mass-2-72kg-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your Like button set up to point to http://www.pinnaclesupplement.co.uk – so when people klick like, they only get the “default thing”, your basic site’s description.

If you want customers to like a specific product page’s URL – then you should point the `href` parameter of the Like button there.

Comment: ahh right ok, so how can i go about garbing the URL dynamically? this is how i am currently doing it, $og_url = JURI::current(); and then $doc->addCustomTag('<meta property="og:url" content="'.$og_url.'"/>');

Comment: also this does appear to be grabbing the correct URL and placing it in the og_url meta description so i still dont quite understand what is going wrong?

Comment: It’s not about the meta tag, it’s about the piece where you actually embed the like button: `<fb:like href="/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>` – you’re saying right there, that you want it to like your base URL, `/`, instead of the actual one.

Comment: I see now, i have just tried to change this now to use the current URL, however whenever i do anything accept hard code the href it uses facebook as the default URL, do you have an example bit of code i could use in there that will make this work? its not plausible for me hard code this for every single item

Comment: i seem to have manages to correctly populate the href, however now when i click the like button nothing is being posted on facebook and the balloon that appears when clicking the like button no longer has any of the product info in it?